# Going to the beach makes/make me very happy

Tags: word-choice

Make or makes? Please explain me why. "Makes" shouldn't be used only for 3rd person singular?

Comment: This *is* third person singular.

Comment: The subject of _makes_ is a gerund clause: _(My) going to the beach_. (The subject of _going_ is deleted because _me_ shows up in the verb phrase.) Of course clauses don't point to nouns so they don't have gender or number. So, the rule is: **All** clauses (gerund, infinitive, _Wh_-, _that_, whatever, of any type) that act as noun phrases act as **singular neuter** noun phrases. Therefore it's _makes_ (singular), for the verb; and if you need a pronoun, it's _it_ (singular neuter). Got all that?

Answer (score 1):

"makes" is correct.  "Going", the subject, agrees with "makes" (I think "going to the beach is called a "gerund phrase").

Comment: D'oh.  I guess that makes the gerund phrase "Going to the beach" the subject, technically, but the "going" part is still the significant bit for verb agreement.

Answer (score 0):

As @choster notes, this *is* third person singular. "Going to the beach" is the subject of the verb, and "me" is not the subject, but the object.

It might be clearer that this is in fact the case by rephrasing it as:

> Going to the beach... it makes me very happy.

Here it's clear that the subject of "makes" is "it".